# Convert a String to floating point number in java

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to convert the string pprice to a floating point number. However, the object's price attribute(floating pt type) is setting as 0.00.. Can someone pls tell me what's wrong?

```
String pprice="60.0"
String tokens[]=pprice.split(".");
if(tokens.length>=2)
{
    int a=Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    int b=Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    float a1=(float)a;
    float b1=(float)b;
    Float price=a1+(b1/100);
    prod.setProductPrice(price);
}
else if(tokens.length==1)
{
    int a=Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    float a1=(float)a;
    prod.setProductPrice(a1);
}
```

Comment: You really don't want to treat monetary values as binary floating-point numbers, though: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FloatingPointCurrency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    String tokens[]=pprice.split(".");
```

The argument to split is a regular expression, and "." is a regular expression that matches *any single character*. To match only the dot, you need to escape it with a backslash, and since the backslash is also special, you need to double it.

```
    String tokens[]=pprice.split("\\.");
```

Change that and your code should work.

You'd probably be better off using one of the parse methods mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: It worked!! Thank u so much!! When i tried using the parse methods mentioned in the other answers, i was getting: java.lang.NumberFormatException.. Your method worked very nicely.. i got 60.00!! :)

Answer (score 7):

Use Double.parseDouble(string) or Float.parseFloat(string);

Comment: The exception message usually includes the string it failed to parse - it could be that pprice is locale adapted (e.g. 60,0 rather than 60.0) and if so you should use NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(yourLocale).parse(pprice).floatValue(). What does the error message say?

Comment: I'm using LogCat.. it just gave me the line number which showed the line where i wrote Float.parseFloat(tokens[0]) at.. i dont understand why it didnt work.. when i tried Float.parseFloat(pprice), i got the same exception.. but i figured this was because there was a "." in the string..

Comment: Could you print the value of pprice before you're trying to parse it, just so that we can see the string it doesn't handle?

Comment: So, you're saying that Double.parseDouble("60.0") gives you a NumberFormatException? Then I'm mistaken about the specs of Double.parseDouble, or there's something wrong with your SDK installation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `float.parseFloat("60.0");` or `Double.parseDouble("60.0");`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use something like:

```
float price = Float.valueOf(pprice.trim());
```

(equivalent to Float.parseFloat(string))

Answer (score 1):

```
float urfloat=Float.parseFloat(String string)
```